# Cookies Causing 500 Internal Error

Tags: php, cookies

Im developing a simple app (1 page) and I'm running into an interesting snag. The initial visit works fine with no problems. Subsequent visits I get 500 Internal Error and can't do anything. I initially thought it was a problem with the PHP version with 1&1 or caching as the first visit worked fine.

After some digging I found out it was the cookies causing the problem. In Firefox, if I clear the cookies, the site works but again, subsequent visits fail.

I don't even really know how to go a out troubleshooting and/or fixing this issue so any insight would be helpful.

App specs:
1&1 Shared Hosting
PHP 5.4.0 Beta 1 (enabled dev version as 1&1 for whatever reason won't implement 5.3)
Fat Free PHP framework (http://fatfree.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Please show your code, specifically where you have set cookies and anywhere that you have used a value from `$_COOKIE`. And at the top of your script add the lines `error_reporting(-1); ini_set('display_errors',1);` to get the error message.

Comment: 500 error messages get logged in the server's error log. Go look at that first for more details. It'll say exactly why the error occured.

Comment: Are there PHP error logs you can check?

Comment: Can you post your code, to me this seems like an error with the way you handling cookies.

Comment: 500 errors are usually written to the Apache log. Try to see if you can find any from around that time.

Comment: @DaveRandom I should have mentioned that I'm not using cookies at all in my code. The framework could be which I'll be looking into how it handles it now.

Comment: @justin.chmura The most helpful thing here would be an error message - which will be generated when the server returns a 500 error.

Comment: I believe Google Analytics made be the culprit. The only cookies that the site sets are Google Analytics ones. I remove those and it works. I won't be able to test till little bit later but will post back with results. @DaveRandom all that the page displays is "Error 500 - Internal Server Error. An internal server error has occurred! Please try again later." I can view the F3 logs later as well.

Comment: Additional information: after playing with the site at work, I found that of the 4 cookies that Google Analytics sets, if I remove __utma or __utmz, the site loads fine. The problem is then Analytics loads them again so the next visit will error out. I will try removing the Analytics code to see if that at least removes the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app was simple enough I just ditched the framework and wrote some custom functionality and it works now.

I still don't understand exactly what was going on as 1&1 refused to give me any error log information but my custom solution is working.

Thanks everyone for your comments.